# Expression for the density function of a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory, singularity, radon-nikodym

I am working on tomographic methods in which the data is the "distribution" of values along a line rather than an integral. Given a measurable  function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one can define the push forward measure $\mu(s)=\lambda(f^{-1}S)$ for a measurable set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$  where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

The density function $\phi$  is the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\mu/d\lambda$, when that exists, but more generally it is the distributional derivative of the cumulative distribution function $\mu(-\infty,y]$ with respect to $y$, or simply the generalized function associated with the measure $\mu$.

For example if $f$ is constant $c$ then $\phi(y) = \delta(y-c)$ and if $y$ is a non-critcal value of $f$ and $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite 
$$ \phi(y) = \sum_\limits{x \in f^{-1}(y) } \frac{1}{f'(x)}.$$

In the case of an isolated critical point $x$ with $f^{(k)}(x)=0$, $0<k<m$  and $f(x+h) =y + f^{(m)}(x)h^m/m! +o(h^m)$ one  gets a singularity in $\phi$ at $y$.

Is there a complete description of $\phi$ for any smooth functions $f$ in the literature?  What about $[0,1]$ replaced by the closure of a domain with a smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

One difficulty is that the terminology makes it difficult to search for. Distribution also means generalized function, and in the probability literature where one can search for  "probability density function" they are not that interested in random variables that are a smooths functions.

Comment: $\phi$ does not exist when $f$ is a constant. You have defined $\phi$ as the denisty of $\mu$ with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and this denisty may not exist even for smooth functions. $\phi (y)=\delta (y-c)$ does not make sense. Radon Nikodym derivative is defined only when you have absolute continuity.

Comment: Thanks I am interested in conditions under which it exists. So what I want from $\phi$ is
$$\mu(S)=\int_S \phi \lambda$$
For $f=c$ $\mu(S)=1$ if $c\in S$ and zero otherwise. So $\phi$ is the unit measure at $c$, right?

Comment: If you are attempting to get Lebsgue decompositon and a formula for the density of the absolute continuity part of the measure induce by any smooth function you are asking for too much, I think.

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify, When I said $\delta(y-c)$ I mean the Dirac delta measure $\delta_c$  at $c$.

Comment: According to standard definition of Radon Nikodym derivative $\phi $ does not exist when $f=c$. Smoothness of $f$ does not help in getting absolute continuity of the induced measure. $f\equiv 0$ is the smoothest function on earth and the induced measure has no density with respect to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: So as a result of these comments it seems that I should not be thinking of the R-N derivative in the conventional sense but simply trying to find an expression for the measure $\mu$, as a Lebsgue decomposition, as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out.  As a distribution I presume the singular support is just the critical values. Away from critical values I have it so my quest is for the singular part.